# unable to call dropdown in view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter my helper code is

```
function dropdown($data, $select) {

    $list = "<select name='country'>";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $key1 = $value['countrycode'];
        $value1 = $value['countryname'];
        if ($select == $key1)

            $list .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"$key1\">$value1</option>";
        else
            $list .= "<option value=\"$key1\">$value1</option>";

        $key1 = '';
        $value1 = '';
    }
    $list .= "</select>";
    return $list;
}
```

and controller is

```
 function allCountry() {
        $result['data'] = $this->Country_mod->getCountry();
        $data['country_list'] = $result['data'];
    }
```

and model is

```
 function getCountry() {
        $this->db->select("countrycode,countryname");
        $query = $this->db->get('country');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

my actual problem is i am unable to call it in view page when i am calling dropdown it given error Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
i dont know how two handle it

Comment: Your `dropdown()` function is expecting an array into `$data`. Where/how do you call `dropdown` and passing data to it? Or you are expecting `allCountry()` to fulfil `$data` array which is in the local scope of that function and `dropdown()` function has no clue about it?

Comment: How to solve it

Comment: first of all, you could answer my questions as in unclear how you are referring to `$data` values.

Comment: I can Pass it $country_list as an array

Comment: how do you call `dropdown()` function and do you pass ANY array into `$data` variable when calling it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the result from `allCountry` function and to pass it to your `dropdown` generator:

```
<?php
    function allCountry() {
        $result['data'] = $this->Country_mod->getCountry();
        $data['country_list'] = $result['data'];
        return $data; //must return the data
    }
    ...

    $countryData = $this->Country_mod->allCountry();
    ...

    $list = dropdown($countryData, $someCountryCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

in controler file

```
$this->load->view("view",$data);
```

in view file

```
...    
dropdown($country_list);
...
```